# How to Compare from a 2 specific timeframe from a database using a query

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

Im just wondering if it is possible two compare from a two certain time using an sql statement..

I have a table that handles all subject schedule.. Lets say i have a class in Mathematics..
on my Schedule table.. I have a fieldname "starttime" and a fieldname "endtime".. and a field name "day" for what  day on the week that it will be taken..

Lets say I have a subject schedule on "Monday" and the value for "starttime" is 7:00:00AM and that schedule "endtime" is "10:00:00 AM".. And its subject name is Mathematics..

Now, i want to display the subject details for that schedule depending on the time i login.. Lets say I login at 8:00:00AM on Monday.. Then for that schedule it will be "Mathematics" that it will  to display..

I was able to join two different tables by using LEFT JOIN.. and i want to add what i said earlier on this query but i dont know how will i do it.. to compare it unto the two timeframe that i inserted on the database..

Right Now, These are my codes..

I want to compare the "time" = Now unto the two time frames on my database.. so it will only display what subject that i will have to take on this day.. when i Login..

```
      Try
        Dim position As String
        con.Open()

        comm.CommandText = ("SELECT a.user_id, a.first_name,a.last_name, a.course, a.position,a.picture, a.section, b.* from Users as a LEFT JOIN Schedule as b on a.section=b.section where user_id LIKE @field1 ")
        comm.Connection = con
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", "%" & txtRFID.Text & "%")
        dr = comm.ExecuteReader
        While (dr.Read)
            Dim arrImage As Byte()
            arrImage = dr.Item("picture")
            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream(arrImage)
            txtID.Text = (dr("user_id").ToString)
            txtFirstName.Text = (dr("first_name").ToString)
            txtLastName.Text = (dr("last_name").ToString)
            txtCourse.Text = (dr("course").ToString)
            txtSection.Text = (dr("section").ToString)
            position = (dr("position").ToString)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mstream)
            txtSubjName.Text = (dr("subject"))
            txtInstName.Text = (dr("instructor"))
            lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Lime
            lblStatus.Text = "Welcome " + position
            Timer2.Enabled = True

        End While
        Dim day As Date = Now
        Dim time As Date = Now
        Dim datestg As Date = Now
        Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("hh:mm:ss"))
        TextBox2.Text = time.ToString("hh:mm")
        Console.WriteLine(day.ToString("ddd"))
        TextBox1.Text = day.ToString("dddd")
        Console.WriteLine(datestg.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy"))
        TextBox3.Text = datestg.ToString("MMMM dd,yyyy")

        comm.Dispose()
        comm.Parameters.Clear()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
        lblStatus.Text = "UnIdentified User!"

    End Try
```

Comment: What are the data types of "starttime",  "endtime", and "day"? Time, time and int? If so, what is the int value for Monday?

Comment: the data type of starttime and endtime is DateTime.. And for the day.. i varchar(50)..

Comment: It would have been easier if you had used the `time` data type available since version 1008 of SQL Server. As you are using `datetime`s, what is the date of the entries? I. e. is 7:00 am coded as `Jan, 1, 1900, 7:00 am`?